# How do I disassociate a filetype and mode?

Tags: major-mode

I think the Change Log mode in emacs (spacemacs) acts crazily and I want to turn it off when editing my CHANGELOG. How do I do that for good?

Comment: FYI, I've updated my sample code, in case you copied it verbatim.  I saw you already accepted the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `change-log-mode` exists to help with viewing and editing Change Log files like the one Emacs itself uses.  You might consider simply modifying the mode's settings so it behaves like you want instead of "throwing the baby out with the bath water" so to speak. :)

Since that wasn't the specific question you asked, you can use a different mode by modifying `auto-mode-alist`.  This variable tells Emacs what mode to load based on a regex matching of the file being loaded.  For Change Logs, by default, it shows this:

```lisp
'(("[cC]hange\\.?[lL]og?\\'" . change-log-mode)
  ("[cC]hange[lL]og[-.][0-9]+\\'" . change-log-mode)
  ("\\$CHANGE_LOG\\$\\.TXT" . change-log-mode)
  ("[cC]hange[lL]og[-.][-0-9a-z]+\\'" . change-log-mode))
```

You can simply get rid of it like this:

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist (rassq-delete-all 'change-log-mode auto-mode-alist))
```

You shouldn't need to do that, though, as adding to the list overrides settings.  So you can just replace it like this:

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append '(("[cC]hange\\.?[lL]og?\\'" . text-mode)
                ("[cC]hange[lL]og[-.][0-9]+\\'" . text-mode)
                ("\\$CHANGE_LOG\\$\\.TXT" . text-mode)
                ("[cC]hange[lL]og[-.][-0-9a-z]+\\'" . text-mode))
              auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: You don't need the `setq auto-mode-alist` bit there, `add-to-list` modifies the list in-place.

Comment: @rpluim ah right.  I shouldn't type so fast. :)

Comment: Hmm, you seem to have omitted quoting for your string literals.  That doesn't actually work, does it? Also see `rassq-delete-all`.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks for the correction.  What happened was I did `(print "%s" auto-mode-alist)` and copied the result, which stripped the quotes out.  I've fixed up the examples.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```el
(defalias 'change-log-mode #'text-mode)
```

---

This suggestion has (not unreasonably) garnered some down-votes.  I'm not deleting it, but it needs some extra notes:

1. cyberbisson's answer is the correct solution to the question in the title: "How do I disassociate a filetype and mode?".  In general, that's the sensible approach to take (and is of course completely fine in this case).
2. My suggestion was 100% aimed at the specific use-case of eradicating `change-log-mode`.  I'm mostly sure this mode has a sufficiently-limited set of uses that *in practice* clobbering the mode function is going to be fine.  Assuming that is indeed the case, this is just a very very easy approach.
3. I'm not recommending this approach as a *general* solution (although it would undoubtedly also work fine in practice in numerous other cases).  DoMiNeLa10 commented that it might break things, and that's definitely possible for arbitrary uses of defalias to clobber modes, but (I suspect) not likely to be a problem for this example.
4. This approach has one advantage (or disadvantage) over the `auto-mode-alist` approach in that it also prevents `change-log-mode` from being triggered in any other way.  This is probably not relevant, but worth pointing out.
5. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `add-log` <kbd>RET</kbd> would redefine `change-log-mode` to its normal value, if you wanted to do that.

Comment: I am not the DV, but I wonder why this got downvoted. Perhaps there is a more idiomatic way?

Comment: I didn't DV (and I won't, because this solution will work), but that's an awfully big hammer for this nail.  You won't be able to even manually use the mode of you do it this way.

Comment: The issue was "Change Log mode ... acts crazily" and they didn't want to use it, so it didn't seem entirely unreasonable to suggest a way in which nothing would ever cause it to be used.  (My first inclination was updating `auto-mode-alist`, but I went with this approach on purpose, as big a hammer as it is.)

Comment: @phils this solution is bad, because overriding `change-log-mode` could lead to unexpected breakage.

Comment: I can come up with some scenarios, but honestly, I think it would be fine in practice for this particular case.  cyberbisson's answer certainly matches the question title better, though.